# Where to add activity_main.xml data when there is no layout folder because of the java files

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am creating an android application on Android studio and my application is using java that means no /res/layout while there is some stuff online tutorials tell me to add to activity_main.xml please help me out how can I do that when there is no /res/layout ..

Comment: Did you check the folder manually to see if there's a folder?

Comment: You are welcome to create `res/layout/` yourself. Right-click over `res/` and choose New > "Android resource directory" from the context menu.

Comment: @GeorgeRappel yes i check it my self but there's nothing.

Comment: @CommonsWare is it ok to create activity_main.xml in the self created layout folder even though my game is all ready to play i am trying to put AdMob for which i need activity_main.xml.

Comment: "i am trying to put AdMob for which i need activity_main.xml" -- I am not aware that AdMob requires you to use a layout file, let alone one named `activity_main.xml`. These "online tutorials" that you have read are *examples*.

Comment: So @CommonsWare am i free to create an activity_main.xml file ? I have `gameactivity.java` though.

Comment: You are welcome to do whatever you want. If your goal is to put ads in your game, you should research *how to put ads in your game*. For example, using a search engine to search for `add admob to android game` turns up documentation like [this page](https://developers.google.com/admob/games?hl=en), which shows how to add AdMob ads to a game, without creating an `activity_main.xml` file.